# How to handle metastable input using a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, c, signal-processing, metastability

I have a metastability problem and I want to know how to best handle it using the C language.

**The problem**
I have two GPIOs that define the state of my system.
Because of the conditioning circuit, they do not change state simultaneously.
This creates an undesirable intermediate state.

[image]

To my knowledge, in FPGA, this is called a metastability problem.
Maybe, we could also call this a resynchronization problem.

**The question**
How would you handle this situation in an elegant way?

Please note that, while in my contrived example I could just look at GPIO 2, I'm looking for a general solution to address this problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but in software you can simply use an if statement to check if both inputs are in the desired state, and if not, wait for them to converge.  This isn't really a metastability problem either, since by the time your software sees the inputs, the GPIO block has already resolved any metastability.

Comment: Metastability is when the voltage on an *actual* electrical input such as GPIO 1 or 2 spends too much time between 0 and 1 or when that transition intersects with the clock edge both of which confuse the transistor. Your observed state is purely logical.

Comment: It's not clear to me why your problem wouldn't be solved by a simple logical `AND` function. Maybe you need to expand on the actual issue you're trying to solve...

Answer (score 5):

This is not what's known as a metastability problem. This is a state coding problem.

You have designed your system so that on transitioning from one state to another, it flips two signals, which can then be skewed before reception.

The tidiest way around this is to use [Gray Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) to encode your states. This ensures that on any state transition, only one output changes, removing your issue.

If you can't recode your states, then your program has to know what the maximum inter-signal skew time is, and wait at least this long after seeing a transition to see if any more arrive, before finally decoding a state change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! `...wait at least this long after seeing a transition to see if any more arrive` this is pretty much what I'm going for right now. I wonder if there's a name for that. right now my function is named `_resynchronizeInputs()`

Answer (score 2):

That is not metastability from the GPIO point of view. The MCU just sees that one GPIO pin changes state first, and the second some time after. Maybe you just need some debouncing.

What you can do is that if the state has changed from previous, you can simply ignore it for a while and wait for some time if the other bit changes too or not, and do a state change only when both bits have been stable for long enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
`simply ignore it for a while` yeah this is pretty much what I'm going for right now. I wonder if there's a name for that. right now my function is named `_resynchronizeInputs()`

Comment: `Maybe you just need some debouncing`. To my understanding, this would not solve the synchronization problem.

Comment: @gberth It is not a synchronization problem. Debouncing is already what you do then, by ignoring input until it has been determined stable. Best is if you know that state is illegal so you know to ignore it. Worst is if it is a legal state but just intermediate between initial and final states. If you told what the GPIO source is then maybe there would be a solution, like the AND of both signals in software. For example a two bit mode select slide switch?